# fill the page with divs excluding some areas

Tags: javascript

Taking the images as an example, I would like to fill the non-red areas with floating divs

[image]

[image]

Knowing the size and location of the red areas, I need an algorithm to programmatically create all the non-red divs in the second image. It doesn't matter if the divs you create overlap, the important thing is that they don't go over the red areas and fill the rest of the page. The ideal would be to create as few divs as possible. I didn't find anything about it...

Comment: You can fill the divs however you like and assign `z-index:1` where then adds the red divs and assign `z-index:2` for them. it should be easy

Comment: Red areas are not divs... I need this trick to create an overlay of non clickable area on the page to constrain the user on an interactive tutorial. Is a complex webapp with many layers and popup menus...

Answer (score 0):

Done by myself.

```js
const fullScreenDiv = document.querySelector('#fullscreendiv')
const fullScreenDivBB = fullScreenDiv.getBoundingClientRect()

const freeAreas = [
  { left: 150, top: 150, right: 300, bottom: 300 },
  { left: 150, top: 400, right: 250, bottom: 600 },
  { left: 350, top: 100, right: 500, bottom: 200 },
  { left: 20, top: 20, right: 35, bottom: 35 },
  { left: 60, top: 10, right: 70, bottom: 80 }
]


const sortedUniq = arr => arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b).filter((item, pos, ary) => !pos || item != ary[pos - 1])
const rectangleOverlapFreeArea = (r) => {
  for(const freeArea of freeAreas){
    if(freeArea.top >= r.bottom || r.top >= freeArea.bottom) continue
    if(freeArea.right <= r.left || r.right <= freeArea.left) continue
    return true;
  }
  return false
}



const tangents = {vertical:[],horizontal:[]}
freeAreas.forEach(fa=>{
  tangents.vertical = [...tangents.vertical,fa.left,fa.right]
  tangents.horizontal = [...tangents.horizontal,fa.top,fa.bottom]
})
sortedUniq(tangents.horizontal)
sortedUniq(tangents.vertical)
tangents.vertical.push(fullScreenDivBB.width)
tangents.horizontal.push(fullScreenDivBB.height)

const rectangles = []
const topLeftBottomRight = {
  tl:{x:0,y:0},
  br:{x:0,y:0}
}
for(let row = 0; row < tangents.horizontal.length; row++){

  topLeftBottomRight.tl.y = row > 0 ? tangents.horizontal[row-1] : 0
  topLeftBottomRight.br.y = tangents.horizontal[row]

  for(let col = 0; col<tangents.vertical.length; col++){
    topLeftBottomRight.tl.x = col > 0 ? tangents.vertical[col-1] : 0
    topLeftBottomRight.br.x = tangents.vertical[col]
    const rectangle = {
      left:topLeftBottomRight.tl.x,
      top:topLeftBottomRight.tl.y,
      right:topLeftBottomRight.br.x,
      bottom:topLeftBottomRight.br.y
    }

    if(rectangleOverlapFreeArea(rectangle)) continue

    const adjacent = rectangles.findIndex(r=>r.right == rectangle.left && r.top == rectangle.top)
    if(adjacent >= 0){
      rectangles[adjacent].right = rectangle.right
      continue
    }
    rectangles.push(rectangle)
  }
}

for(const rectangle of rectangles){
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  fullScreenDiv.appendChild(newDiv)
  newDiv.style.position = 'absolute'
  newDiv.style.left = rectangle.left + 'px'
  newDiv.style.top = rectangle.top + 'px'
  newDiv.style.height = (rectangle.bottom - rectangle.top) + 'px'
  newDiv.style.width = (rectangle.right - rectangle.left) + 'px'
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#009090'
  newDiv.style.boxShadow = '2px 3px 7px black inset' 
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#fullscreendiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="fullscreendiv">
 </div>
 </body>
```